# How to add generic Set to Map (Map<String, Set<String>> map = new TreeMap<>())?

Tags: java, string, dictionary, generics, set

I want to make a phone book with help `Map<String, Set<String>> map = new TreeMap<>()`

**Example:**

```
Anna - 8999
Ira - 8777, 8666
Artur - 5444, 6555
```

where name is key (String), and the phone number is a Set  value, how to specify  phone numbers for each name, i.e. each name must have its own Set Numbers

Comment: where you having problem exactly? `map.put("Ira", Set.of(8777, 8666))`

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you try simply

If you are using `Java 9` and above use

```
Map<String, Set<String>> map = new TreeMap<>();
map.put("Anna", Set.of(8999));
map.put("Ira", Set.of(8777, 8666));
map.put("Artur", Set.of(5444, 6555));
```

If you are using `Java 8` the try

```
Map<String, Set<Integer>> map = new TreeMap<>();
map.put("Anna", Stream.of(8999).collect(Collectors.toSet()));
map.put("Ira", Stream.of(8777, 8666).collect(Collectors.toSet()));
map.put("Artur", Stream.of(5444, 6555).collect(Collectors.toSet()));
```

If you are using old version of `Java` then try

```
Map<String, Set<String>> map = new TreeMap<>();
map.put("Anna", new TreeSet(Arrays.asList(8999)));
map.put("Ira", new TreeSet(Arrays.asList(8777, 8666)));
map.put("Artur", new TreeSet(Arrays.asList(5444, 6555)));
```

Comment: But if the author use jdk 8 or early this construction (Set.of(5444, 6555)) won't work. this feature added in jdk 9

Answer (score 1):

If you using Java 8 then try this:

```
    Map<String, Set<String>> map = new TreeMap<>();
    map.put("Anna", new HashSet(Arrays.asList(8999)));
    map.put("Ira", new HashSet(Arrays.asList(8777, 8666)));
    map.put("Artur",new HashSet(Arrays.asList(5444, 6555)));
```

If your using Java 9+ then use `Set.of`. But note this set created using `of` method is unmodifiable.

Example:

```
Set.of(8999)
```